# URL fragment messes up CSS

Tags: html, css

I am going to have to link to an external website as I am having trouble reproducing this issue in JSFiddle.

For some reason accessing my page with an URL fragment corresponding to an ID that exists on the page appears to pull up certain areas of the document, the behaviour is not reproduced with a non-existant ID. There is no JavaScript on the page which could be causing this behaviour.

This behaviour is consistent in the following (so is unlikely to be a browser bug):

- Google Chrome 31
- Firefox 21
- Internet explorer 8

Live view (accessed: 19/12/13) **Issue resolved - see graphic below**:

- This is the page as it should look: http://sixplusfour.co.uk/encyclopedia/
- This is the page with the named anchor: http://sixplusfour.co.uk/encyclopedia/#pagelist

The error is shown side by side in the following image:

[image: Side by side comparison]

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: `id`s behave like old-style `<a name="">` anchors, so if you name them in the fragment, the browser will jump to the corresponding position. Is that what's confusing you?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz No, I want it to jump to the position. The point is it also moves elements into positions they shouldn't be (see the comparison image which is flush with the top of the browser - and taken at a resolution where there is no scroll-bar).

Comment: Don't know why this is happening, but why do you have margin-top:32 on `#container>#content>post-5>header>h1` instead of a `padding-top` on `#container` (which seems to be what you're after..?)

Comment: @thebjorn because I want that space to be relative to the size of the heading (it is 0.5em - which gets converted to 32 at a base font size of 16)

Comment: Wouldn't a `line-height` be better suited for that purpose?

Comment: @thebjorn I don't see why... the browser default is to use margins to space headers. This allows me to specify top and bottom spacing independent of each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the `:after` pseudo-class of `#pagelist` is causing this. *I have no clue why this is happening* but the `display` doesn't seems to load properly.

This pseudo-class seems like a quick fix. You might want to *delete this pseudo-class* and fix the real problem. *Try to add a `overflow: hidden` to your wrapper* so its floated contents keeps in the flow:

```
.col-group {
   margin-left: -1em;
   margin-right: -1em;
   zoom: 1;
   overflow: hidden; /*new line*/
}
```

I can not test it on reload, but this should work.

### Update

The real problem is probably because the the `base-line` is shifting based on its font. It contains a dot as content. Now this is still not clear why this happens when redirecting. However i suggest to you a empty content for this:

```
.col-group:after {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  content: ""; /* removed dot */
}
```

This should work without modifieng too much.

Comment: +1 Interesting... it seems as if the clearfix doesn't get applied with an url fragment. If you modify one of it's settings in developer tools and cause a repaint it fixes. Thanks... my grid system was inspired by fluidable.com and that is what they use - I am slightly worried they did it on purpose and that removing it and replacing it with an `overflow` could cause unexpected behaviour in some browser.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Updated my post with a solution where you can keep the `:after` pseudo-class and probably fixes the 'real' problem.

Comment: Perfect... works like a dream. You are a CSS god walking among mere mortals.

Comment: @GeorgeReith That's very kind of you ^^ Glad i could help!

Answer (score 3):

If you set `overflow: auto;` on `#container` you start to see why the problem occurs. The contents of `#container` are actually taller than their container. When the URL fragment is in place, the browsers are scrolling *within* `#container` to reach it.

(I haven't yet figured out exactly why, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably linked to a `:focus` or `:hover` selector.

I see this code in your `style.css` :

```
.pagenav li a:focus {
  outline: #114d74 solid 1px;
  outline-offset: -1px;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

Couldn't this be a different value of `padding` or `outline` that makes things change?

Comment: Doesn't look like that's the problem (that seems only related to the menu 'animation' under "Pages").